# Looking for guide line about Razor syntax in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am learning asp.net mvc just going through online tutorial

**1)** `just see <span>@model.Message</span> and @Html.Raw(model.Message)`

suppose if "Hello Word" is stored in Message then "Hello Word" should display if i write statement like
`<span>@model.Message</span>` but i just could not understand what is the special purpose about `@Html.Raw(model.Message)`.
what `@Html.Raw() will render` ?

please discuss with few more example to understand the difference well.

**2)** just see the below two snippet

```
@if (foo) {
  <text>Plain Text</text> 
}

@if (foo) {
  @:Plain Text is @bar
}
```

in which version of html the tag called  was introduce. is it equivalent to

or  what ? what is the purpose of
this tag  ?

just tell me about this `@:Plain Text is @bar`
what is the special meaning of @: ? 
if our intention is to mixing text with expression then can't we write like Plain Text is @bar

**3)** `<span>ISBN@(isbnNumber)</span>`
what it will print ? if 2000 is stored in isbnNumber variable then it may print `<span>ISBN2000</span>. am i right ?`

so tell me what is the special meaning of `@(variable-name)` why bracket along with `@` symbol ?

**4)** just see

```
<span>In Razor, you use the 
@@foo to display the value 
of foo</span>
```

if foo has value called god then what this `@@foo` will print ?

**5 )** see this and  guide me about few more syntax given below point wise

**a)** `@(MyClass.MyMethod<AType>())`

**b)**

```
@{
  Func<dynamic, object> b = 
   @<strong>@item</strong>;
}
@b("Bold this")
```

**c)** `<div class="@className foo bar"></div>`

**6)** see this

```
@functions
{
string SayWithFunction(string message)
{
return message;
}
}
@helper SayWithHelper(string message)
{

Text: @message

}
@SayWithFunction("Hello, world!")
@SayWithHelper("Hello, world!")
```

what they are trying to declare ? function ?
what kind of syntax it is ?
it seems that two function has been declare in two different way ? please explain this points with more sample. thanks

### Few More question

**7)**

```
@{
  Func<dynamic, object> b = @<strong>@item</strong>;
}
<span>This sentence is @b("In Bold").</span>
```

what the meaning of above line ? is it anonymous delegate?
when some one will call `@b("In Bold")` then what will happen ?

**8)**
    @{
      var items = new[] { "one", "two", "three" };
    }

```
<ul>
@items.List(@<li>@item</li>)
</ul>
```

tell me something about List() function and from where the item variable come ?

**9)**

```
@{
    var comics = new[] { 
        new ComicBook {Title = "Groo", Publisher = "Dark Horse Comics"},
        new ComicBook {Title = "Spiderman", Publisher = "Marvel"}
    };
}

<table>
@comics.List(
  @<tr>
    <td>@item.Title</td>
    <td>@item.Publisher</td>
  </tr>)
</table>
```

please explain briefly the above code. thanks

Comment: You might be better off breaking these out into separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Any kind of `@Variable` output makes MVC automatically encode the value. That is to say if `foo = "Joe & Dave"`, then `@foo` becomes `Joe &amp; Dave` automatically. To escape this behavior you have `@Html.Raw`.

**2)** `<text></text>` is there to help you when the parser is having trouble. You have to keep in mind Razor goes in and out of HTML/Code using the semantics of the languages. that is to say, it knows it's in HTML using the XML parser, and when it's in C#/VB by its syntax (like braces or `Then..End` respectively). When you want to stray from this format, you can use `<text>`. e.g.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        @foreach (var item in items) {
          @item.Description
          <text></li><li></text>
        }
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here you're messing with the parser because it no longer conforms to "standard" HTML blocks. The `</li>` would through razor for a loop, but because it's wrapped in `<text></text>` it has a more definitive way of knowing where code ends and HTML begins.

**3)** Yes, the parenthesis are there to help give the parser an **explicit** definition of what should be executed. Razor makes its best attempt to understand what you're trying to output, but sometimes it's off. The parenthesis solve this. e.g.

```
@Foo.bar
```

If you only had `@Foo` defined as a string, Razor would inevitably try to look for a `bar` property because it follows C#'s naming convention (this would be a very valid notation in C#, but not our intent). So, to avoid it from continuing on we can use parenthesis:

```
@(Foo).bar
```

A notable exception to this is when there is a single trailing period. e.g.

```
Hello, @name.
```

The Razor parser realizes nothing valid (in terms of the language) follows, so it just outputs `name` and a period thereafter.

**4)** `@@` is the escape method for razor when you need to actually print `@`. So, in your example, you'd see `@foo` on the page in plain text. This is useful when outputting email addresses directly on the page, e.g.

```
bchristie@@contoso.com
```

Now razor won't look for a `contoso.com` variable.

**5)** You're seeing various shortcuts and usages of how you bounce between valid C# code and HTML. Remember that you can go between, and the HTML you're seeing is really just a compiled `IHtmlString` that is finally output to the buffer.

Comment: please have a look i post some few more question at bottom. if possible please answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

### **1.**

By default, Razor automatically html-encodes your output values (`<div>` becomes `&lt;div&gt;`). `@Html.Raw` should be used when you explicitly want to output the value as-is without any encoding (very common for outputting JSON strings in the middle of a `<script>`).

---

### **2.**

The purpose of `<text>` and `@:` is to escape the regular Razor syntax flow and output literal text values. for example:

```
// i just want to print "Haz It" if some condition is true
@if (Model.HasSomething) { Haz It } // syntax error
@if (Model.HasSomething) { <text>Haz It</text> } // just fine
```

As of `@:`, it begins a text literal until the next line-feed (enter), so:

```
@if (Model.HasSomething) { @:Haz It } // syntax error, no closing '}' encountered

// just fine
@if (Model.HasSomething)
{
    @:Haz It
}
```

---

### **3.**

By default, if your `@` is inside a quote/double-quotes (`<tr id="row@item.Id"`), Razor interprets it as a literal and will not try to parse it as expression (for obvious reasons), but sometimes you **do** want it to, then you simply write `<tr id="row@(item.Id")`.

---

### **4.**

The purpose of `@@` is simply to escape '@'. when you want to output '@' and don't want Razor to interpret is as an expression. then in your case `@@foo` would print '@foo'.

---

### **5.**

**a.** `@(MyClass.MyMethod<AType>())` would simply output the return value of the method (using `ToString()` if necessary).

**b.** Yes, Razor does let you define some kind of inline functions, but usually you better use Html `Helpers` / `Functions` / `DisplayTemplates` (as follows).

**c.** See above.

---

### 6.

As of **Razor Helpers**, see http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx